# htaccess - Strip everything after extension

Tags: .htaccess

We have a funny issue on our website. Our server is allowing a second site to stack on top of the current site and the search engines are finding them for some reason.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
 http://www.rippedsheets.com/laser/100742-6_winelabels.html/matte.html
```

I would like to strip everything after the first extension.

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
 http://www.rippedsheets.com/laser/100742-6_winelabels.html
```

Here is what I have tried...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^html/.*\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It mostly works, but it changes all the links on the site to www.www.rippedsheets.com

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.[^./]+)/.+$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you want to keep this rule specific to `.html` only?

Comment: When implemented, it redirects everything to a 404.
It needs to match html, htm, php

Here is most of our htaccess

<Files ~ “^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])”>
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes

# as per netsol forums, CGI-Compiled PHP
#AddHandler Extension_Type .html .htm .php3 .php4 .php
#Action Extension_Type /cgi-bin/php.dat
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddType text/x-vcard .vcf

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1